# Move up product data woocommerce on mobile

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, customization

is there a way ON MOBILE to move the 3 dropdowns section to the above the product name and gallery image?

I am using the woocommerce plugin and for the dropdowns im using the PRODUCT DATA - VAriable product section.

check the link:
[Website](http://www.jetsurfus.com/product/pro-race/)

Answer (score 0):

I would need more about your actual code (or a demo version) to achieve what you exactly want. You could use a bit of jQuery in your *function.php*, the following code as not been tested but the logic is there:

```
/*Move the variation div to another created one
======================================================================= */
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'move_variations_product_tab' );
function move_variations_product_tab() {
  if (is_product()) :
        $product = wc_get_product( get_the_ID() );
        if($product->is_type( 'composite' )){
   ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $(window).load(function() {
                $( ".variations_form" ).wrap( "<div id='variations-content'></div>" );
                $( ".woocommerce-product-gallery" ).before( "<div class='container product-before-gallery'></div>" );
                document.getElementsByClassName("product-before-gallery")[0].appendChild(
                document.getElementById("variations-content")
                );
            });
        });
   </script>
<?php
        }
endif;
}
```

Replace "product-short" by the container of your description.

1. Wrapping around the div you want to move.
2. Creating a new class before the desired location
3. Move the wrapped div (#variations-content) under the newly created one
   (.product-before-gallery).

Hope that helps! Let me know how it goes and give more info if you needs help.

Cheers

Comment: hello! i just seen this response. im going to try and let you know about it. thanks for help.